# Android Toggle Button - Material Design

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-button, android-togglebutton

How do I implement the Toggle Buttons as specified in Material Design guidelines [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-toggle-buttons)?

Is it available out of the box from Android Design Support Library or is there any third party library available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: There is official support now! See the other answers below for links/usage.

## Original post:

### Current Library Support: No.

As of the Support Library v23.2 the current `ToggleButton` implementation does *not* behave nor is it styled as outlined in the referenced Material Design Guidelines.

Material guidelines:

[image: sample Material toggle button]

Current support library styling:

[image: current support library ToggleButton]

Note that the buttons don't meet up together in groups surrounded by rounded borders, text is used instead of icons, and the accent color is used as an underline instead of a darkened background to indicate an 'on' status.

### Is there an external library: Not yet.

I'm not aware of any defacto standard library to implement a Material ToggleButton, but there are probably a few small, barely tested ones out there, I hope? Unfortunately, Stackoverflow discourages Answers that are just links to external third-party libraries. So you'll need to search on your own, or create a custom view yourself to implement the current Material design guidelines.

Comment: Again, not encouraging linking to various third-party libraries, but the closest third-party library I've found so far is https://github.com/jlhonora/multistatetogglebutton

Answer (score 16):

I am also looking for something like a `ToggleButtonBar` for quite some time.

> Material guidelines:
>   [image: sample Material toggle button]

I was able to achieve it abusing RadioButtons:

[image]

To achieve this single selection ButtonBar, I created a `ToggleButton` style for the radio buttons and created a RadioGroup.

Add this to your res/values/**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="ToggleButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:foreground">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
</style>
```

For the background ColorStateList create a res/drawable/**toogle_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_hover" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_normal" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_active" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_active" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_hover" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_normal_off" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_normal" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <color android:color="@color/toggle_hover" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

The append your res/values/**colors.xml** by:

```
<color name="toggle_hover">@color/gray</color>
<color name="toggle_normal">@color/gainsboro</color>
<color name="toggle_active">@color/silver</color>
<color name="toggle_normal_off">@color/darkgray</color>

<color name="gainsboro">#DCdCdC</color>
<color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
<color name="darkgray">#a9a9a9</color>
<color name="gray">#808080</color>
```

In your layout file use this code snippet, to create a material toggle button group. In my case it's the **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/ToggleButton"
                android:text="First" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/ToggleButton"
                android:text="Second" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/ToggleButton"
                android:text="Third" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I used a CardView as a wrapper for the group to achieve the rounded corners. Unfortunately on Android versions lower than Lollipop the rounded corners will result in a Padding of the CardView. You can for sure apply your own styling here with other colors or icons instead of text or both. Just create your own StateLists for those cases.

> Toggle button requirements:
>
> - Have at least three toggle buttons in a group
> - Label buttons with text, an icon, or both
>
> The following combinations are recommended:
>
> - Multiple and unselected
> - Exclusive and unselected
> - Exclusive only

**NOTE:** for using CardView, you need to add it's dependency to your apps build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
```

Comment: The following line in your styles.xml will not build:  <item name="android:foreground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>  Android Studio displays ?attr/selectableItemBackground in red.  Says "Cannot resolve symbol"  Know what's going on here?

Comment: Yea, some stuff changed, now need to use android namespace infront of attr/ => "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
Updated the answer accordingly...

Comment: Awesome! But I would use <item name="android:gravity">center</item> instead of paddings in theme

Answer (score 12):

Google finally caught up with us and there's now an official toggle group in the Material library:

https://material.io/components/buttons#toggle-button

## Older Post:

I've created a ToggleButton library that adheres to the Material Design guidelines:

https://github.com/rcketscientist/ToggleButtons

`compile 'com.anthonymandra:ToggleButtons:2.0.0'`

[image]

Comment: It just won't look right below 21. There's compat stuff that needs to be done. Check out `CardView`. ATM I'm using it in a 21+ app so I haven't ported the compat code, but it's not terribly hard although it is ugly spaghetti code.

Comment: I've ported it down to API 9 in version 2.0.

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button-toggle-group/            Page doesn't exist anymore... :(

Answer (score 4):

I hope this can help you!

http://takeoffandroid.com/android-views/material-toggle-switch-using-appcompat-v7/

import:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

swt = (SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.Switch);
swt.setOnCheckedChangeListener (this);
swt.setChecked (true);
```

Listener:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {

        case R.id.Switch:

            if(!isChecked){

                Toast.makeText (SwitchActivity.this,"Err Switch is off!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText (SwitchActivity.this,"Yes Switch is on!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/Switch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff=""
    android:text="Toggle Switch"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
    android:textOn=""
    android:button="@null"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`MaterialButtonToggleGroup`**.

Something like:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to adjust the spacing between buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SwitchCompat](https://materialdoc.com/components/selection-controls/#switch) if your activity has backwards compatibility.See below example.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checked="true"/>
```

Happy coding :D